# iOS - Can we convert vector pdf to pngs at run time?

Tags: ios, image, pdf, vector, dynamically-generated

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

I have supported vector pdfs through out the project by adding pdfs in xcassets like this:[image]

So when we build our project, Xcode convert pdf into @1x, @2x, and @3x PNG files. And when we run the application, iOS automatically pick the appropriate @1x, @2x, or @3x image that Xcode generated based on the device requirements.

**Issue:**

In one screen, our icons are dynaminc. That means we get pdf images through API. I am not sure how xcode can convert these pdfs at run time.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library called `UIImage-PDF` which you can use to load your PDFs into a `UIImage` at runtime. https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF

Comment: Accepted your answer as per library description. But unfortunately its not working. I am getting pdf url from server and while using imageWithPDFURL:atSize method i am getting following error: <Error>: CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15.

Comment: This is usually tied to a bad URL passed in. As a test, try hard-coding a known valid URL and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: Confirming this library works for pdf files that are inside document folder and loading them into UIImage during runtime